# Is it possible to automatically create queues without RabbitAutoConfiguration.class? AMQP

Tags: spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm using 2.1.0.RELEASE version of Spring boot with AMQP. Unfortunetly I need to connect to several different RabbitMQ servers. I had to exclude `RabbitAutoConfiguration.class` besause due to changes in above version of spring it's impossible to start without one of the ConnectionFactory beans as primary, but even if I set one of them as `@Primary`, obviously it doesn't work, because how would amqp/spring-boot know which queue to create on which server...

so, is it possible to automatically create queues on different servers with auto configuration disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a `RabbitAdmin` for each connection factory.

By default all components will be declared on all brokers, but you can add conditions. See [Conditional Declaration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#conditional-declaration).

> By default, all queues, exchanges, and bindings are declared by all `RabbitAdmin` instances (assuming they have `auto-startup="true"`) in the application context.

```java
@Bean
public Queue queue1() {
    Queue queue = new Queue("foo");
    queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin1());
    return queue;
}
```